# `rtserver-id` turns to `rtserver - id` in java string

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have this code:

```
public void foo (){
        String script =
                "var aLocation = {};" +
                        "var aOffer = {};" +

                        "var aAdData = " +
                        "{ " +
                        "location:  aLocation, " +
                        "offer:    aOffer " +
                        " };" +

                        "var aClientEnv = " +
                        " { " +
                        "    sessionid:     \"\", " +
                        "   cookie:        \"\", " +
                        "   rtserver-id: 1,   " +
                        "       lon:           34.847, " +
                        "       lat:           32.123, " +
                        "       venue:         \"\", " +
                        "    venue_context: \"\", " +

                        "    source:        \"\"," +   // One of the following (string) values: ADS_PIN_INFO,
                        // ADS_0SPEED_INFO, ADS_LINE_SEARCH_INFO,
                        // ADS_ARROW_NEARBY_INFO, ADS_CATEGORY_AUTOCOMPLETE_INFO,
                        // ADS_HISTORY_LIST_INFO
                        // (this field is also called "channel")

                        "    locale:        \"\"" + // ISO639-1 language code (2-5 characters), supported formats:
                        " };" +


                        "W.setOffer(aAdData, aClientEnv);";

            javascriptExecutor.executeScript(script);
}
```

I have two q:

1. when I debug and copy `script` value I see a member `rtserver - id` instead of `rtserver-id`
   how can it be? the code throws an exception because of this.

Even if i remove this `rtserver-id` member (and there is not exception thrown)

I evaluate `aLocation` in this browser console and get `"variable not defined"`. How can this be?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't expect `rtserver-id` to be a valid identifier anyway. Are you sure this actually has anything to do with Java? If you just want valid JSON, try putting it in quotes... It would be helpful if you'd show a *minimal* example, after working out whether the problem is transferring the script to the Javascript executor or something else.

Comment: I'll try. but how can I explain that even without this problematic member, I still cannot access these vars via the browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rtserver-id` isn't a valid identifier - so if you want it as a field/property name, you need to quote it. You can see this in a Chrome Javascript console, with no need for any Java involved:

```
> var aClientEnv = { sessionId: "", rtserver-id: 1 };
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

```
> var aClientEnv = { sessionId: "", "rtserver-id": 1 };
```

> undefined

```
> aClientEnv
```

> Object {sessionId: "", rtserver-id: 1}

Basically I don't think anything's adding spaces - you've just got an invalid script. You can easily add the quotes in your Java code:

```
"   \"rtserver-id\": 1,   " +
```

Comment: I'll try. but how can I explain that even without this problematic member, I still cannot access these vars via the browser console?

Comment: @EladBenda: It's not clear to me what you mean, but that sounds like it's an entirely separate problem, which has nothing to do with the error you originally asked about. (It's not clear to me exactly how you're running this code at all.)